# Checkbox / radio is checked="checked" in HTML but it looks like unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, attr

I'm trying to ensure that user can only select one checkbox, but it looks like nothing is checked. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="formField rsform-block rsform-block-typprofilu">
    <br>
    <input name="form[typprofilu][]" type="checkbox" value="Montreal (Oceľ)" id="typprofilu0" checked="checked">
    <label for="typprofilu0">Montreal (Oceľ)</label>
    <input name="form[typprofilu][]" type="checkbox" value="Halifax (Oceľ)" id="typprofilu1">
    <label for="typprofilu1">Halifax (Oceľ)</label>
    <input name="form[typprofilu][]" type="checkbox" value="Calgary (Hliník)" id="typprofilu2">
    <label for="typprofilu2">Calgary (Hliník)</label>
    <input name="form[typprofilu][]" type="checkbox" value="Niagara (Hliník)" id="typprofilu3">
    <label for="typprofilu3">Niagara (Hliník)</label>
    <input name="form[typprofilu][]" type="checkbox" value="Hudson (Hliník)" id="typprofilu4">
    <label for="typprofilu4">Hudson (Hliník)</label><br>
    <span id="component781" class="formNoError">Invalid Input</span>
    <br>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.rsform-block-typprofilu input#typprofilu0[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',true); 

    jQuery('body').on('click','.rsform-block-typprofilu input[name="form[typprofilu][]"]',function(){
                jQuery('.rsform-block-typprofilu input[name="form[typprofilu][]"]').attr('checked', false);
                var whatIsChecked = jQuery(this).attr('id');
                //var isChecked = jQuery(this).is(':checked');   
                jQuery(this).attr('id',whatIsChecked).attr('checked',true);
            });
```

EDITED: solution with radio buttons

```
<div class="formField rsform-block rsform-block-typprofilu">
        <br>
        <input name="form[typprofilu]" type="radio" value="Montreal (Oceľ)" id="typprofilu0" checked="checked"><label for="typprofilu0">Montreal (Oceľ)</label><input name="form[typprofilu]" type="radio" value="Halifax (Oceľ)" id="typprofilu1"><label for="typprofilu1">Halifax (Oceľ)</label><input name="form[typprofilu]" type="radio" value="Calgary (Hliník)" id="typprofilu2"><label for="typprofilu2">Calgary (Hliník)</label><input name="form[typprofilu]" type="radio" value="Niagara (Hliník)" id="typprofilu3"><label for="typprofilu3">Niagara (Hliník)</label><input name="form[typprofilu]" type="radio" value="Hudson (Hliník)" id="typprofilu4"><label for="typprofilu4">Hudson (Hliník)</label><br>
        <span id="component782" class="formNoError">Invalid Input</span>
        <br>
    </div>

 jQuery('.rsform-block-typprofilu input#typprofilu0[type="radio"]').attr('checked',true);

jQuery('body').on('click','.rsform-block-typprofilu input[name="form[typprofilu]"]',function(){ // ez a radiok kozul a valasztasom
    jQuery('.rsform-block-typprofilu input[name="form[typprofilu]"]').attr('checked', false);
var whatIsChecked = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var isChecked = jQuery(this).is(':checked');

     jQuery(this).attr('id',whatIsChecked).attr('checked',true);
});
```

It doesnt change ... the selected is the first ... but in the HTML it seems it change the checked attr.

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons?

Comment: You can switch the checkboxes with radiobuttons, that will solve your problem right away because they are hardwired to allow only one selection.

Comment: because with radio buttons I cant change the selection on the second click.

Comment: @lostika see my answer below with a solution to your unselect problem.

Comment: After using prop() radio is change but doesnt have 'checked' attribute in the code http://jsfiddle.net/lostika86/HfTGG/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want one to be selected within a group of checkboxes then why not use radio buttons instead? They provide this functionality natively.

```
<input type="radio" name="">
```

If you then want the ability to deselect a radio button (similar to checkbox functionality) then you can implement that using JavaScript.

```
var radios = $(':radio');

radios.on('click', function() {
  var radio = $(this);

  // because .is(:checked) is true AS
  // you check, we use our own flag that
  // is only true AFTER you check        
  radio.trigger(radio.data('ischecked') ? 'uncheck' : 'check');
});

// when the radio selection is changed, fire 
// the uncheck event on the selected radio's 
// sibling that was checked
radios.on('change', function() {
  var siblings = $(':radio[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this);

  siblings.each(function() {
    var sibling = $(this);
    if (sibling.data('ischecked')) {
      sibling.trigger('uncheck');
    }  
  });
});

// custom check / uncheck events
radios.on('check uncheck', function(e) {
  var checked = (e.type === 'check');
  $(this).data('ischecked', checked).attr('checked', checked);
});

// make sure all radios have the necessary 
// ischecked flag on DOM ready
radios.filter(':checked').each(function(i, r) {
  $(this).trigger('check');
});
```

You can also make radio buttons look like checkboxes (in modern browsers excluding IE) if you prefer that styling:

```
input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;
  -ms-appearance: checkbox;     /* not currently supported */
  -o-appearance: checkbox;      /* not currently supported */
  appearance: checkbox;      
}
```

**[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhwRU/7/)**

Comment: I changed to radio, but I cant change other than the first which I set first

Comment: Nothing happens :( var radio = jQuery(this);

  if (radio.is(':checked')) {
    radio.attr('checked', false);
  }  
  else{
   radio.attr('checked', true);
  }

Comment: @lostika sorry, I threw that together too quick without testing... I've updated my answer with working JS and a link to a demo on jsfiddle

Comment: check that you should click twice on the radio, and in the html code there is 2 or 3 button attr checked .. :/

Comment: @lostika - http://jsfiddle.net/dhwRU/2/ ... still not working? :/ sorry, I nipped out to lunch hence the late response!

Comment: I tried to implement it, but after validation I recognized that there is option to select "nothing" ... Im trieng to rewrite it, because it is must to have selected one. By the way thank you for your time

Comment: @lostika - Oh... if you HAVE to have one selected then surely you don't need the "unselect" functionality. Native radio button functionality forces you to select one as they cannot be unselected so just set the "checked" attribute on one of them in the HTML and the user is forced to accept the pre-selection or select a different one. No option to select "nothing".

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the html code in some basic html tags, save this as a .html file and load up in your browser you can clearly see the first checkbox is checked.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="formField rsform-block rsform-block-typprofilu">
<br>
<input name="form[typprofilu][]" type="checkbox" value="Montreal (Oceľ)" id="typprofilu0" checked="checked">
<label for="typprofilu0">Montreal (Oceľ)</label>
<input name="form[typprofilu][]" type="checkbox" value="Halifax (Oceľ)" id="typprofilu1">
<label for="typprofilu1">Halifax (Oceľ)</label>
<input name="form[typprofilu][]" type="checkbox" value="Calgary (Hliník)" id="typprofilu2">
<label for="typprofilu2">Calgary (Hliník)</label>
<input name="form[typprofilu][]" type="checkbox" value="Niagara (Hliník)" id="typprofilu3">
<label for="typprofilu3">Niagara (Hliník)</label>
<input name="form[typprofilu][]" type="checkbox" value="Hudson (Hliník)" id="typprofilu4">
<label for="typprofilu4">Hudson (Hliník)</label><br>
<span id="component781" class="formNoError">Invalid Input</span>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect something wrong with your stylesheet ?

Answer (score 0):

What jQuery library are you using? In jQuery 1.9.1 use `prop` instead of attr, working example: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HFsum/)

I had some problems with prop and attr methods and checked property of the checkbox, and if I remember correct it depends on jQuery version.

Comment: It's known bug [link](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/237), you should use prop for checked attribute.

Comment: the prop() doesnt sets checked the first radio  jQuery('.rsform-block-typprofilu input#typprofilu0[type="radio"]').prop('checked',true);

Comment: But it's not radio, it's checkbox input, your query is empty (length = 0). Use `jQuery('.rsform-block-typprofilu input#typprofilu0[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true);`, you have checkboxes in your question.

Comment: After edition mentioned by others to use radio buttons, I edited my question, and tried with radio. Sorry for inconvience.

Comment: But this example is working fine, no? :) Im using chrome and ie9.

Comment: I think not, selected button doesnt have "checked" attribute after click, check the code..

Comment: If you mean checked attribute in html, read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), the main thing is _Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The checked attribute value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the checked property does._

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Example:

```
   <div class="formField rsform-block rsform-block-typprofilu">
     <input type="radio" value="first" id="1" checked="checked"/>
     <input type="radio" value="second" id="2"/>
     <input type="radio" value="third" id="3"/>
   </div>


   $(document).ready(function(){

     var previousCheckedElem = $("#1")

     $("input[type='radio']").click(function(e){
         previousCheckedElem.attr("checked",false);
         previousCheckedElem = $(this);
     });
   });
```

Made the changes according to your requirement( eg:id, elements).

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fz6v3/1/)

Comment: That JS is unnecessary as that is exactly what radio buttons with the same name do by default

Answer (score 0):

Few observations,

1. While setting the default checked element you are using a complex selector while it can be done using a simple `id` selector `jQuery('#typprofilu0')`.
2. To ignore current item while unchecking other checkboxes you can use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)
3. Then again as everybody suggested use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to change runtime dom properties like `checked` and `selected` instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

It should be as simple as

```
jQuery('#typprofilu0').prop('checked',true); 

jQuery('body').on('click','.rsform-block-typprofilu input[name="form[typprofilu][]"]',function(){
    jQuery('.rsform-block-typprofilu input[name="form[typprofilu][]"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PMBnW/)

Comment: After the mention to use radio buttons I edited my question to radio..not checkbox. Sorry for inconvience

Answer (score 0):

I just realised it's actually easier/lighter from a JS perspective to mimic the radio button functionality using checkboxes than it is to mimic checkbox functionality using radios :/

Try this:

```
var checkboxes = $(':checkbox');

checkboxes.on('click', function() {
  var group = '[name="' + this.name + '"]',
      siblings = checkboxes.filter(group).not(this);
  siblings.filter(':checked').attr('checked', false);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L8J9a/)**

However, if the user decided to disable JS, they would be able to select more than one so that's a decision you'll need to make.